# How to create a Code that generates other code

Tags: python

Since I started learning python a few months back, I have been mesmerized about how with the simple code you could achieve complex tasks.

So, I have been trying to do something like this,

```
list = [1,2,3,4]

statement = ''

if len(list) > 4:
    statement = '[x for x in list if x%%2 == 0]'
else:
    //do something else
```

I know this won't work as **statement** above is just a string, but I hope you get the idea of what am trying to do and hope you could suggest how I should go about it.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense can you state what do want in a clearer way..!

Comment: first of all -> x%2 == 0 and [x for x in list if x%2 == 0] will generate a list not a string

Comment: okay. what am trying to do is generating runnable piece of code. like make that statement string runnable in that same script.

Comment: @ncica yep, i forgot to enclose it in a quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are searching for eval function :

> **Python eval()** The eval() method parses the expression passed to this method and runs python expression (code) within the program.
>
> In simple terms, the eval() method runs the python code (which is
>   passed as an argument) within the program.
>
> The **syntax** of eval() is:
>
> ```
> eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)
> ```
>
> *eval() Parameters:* The eval() takes three parameters:
>
> -expression - this string as parsed and evaluated as a Python
>   expression
>
> -globals (optional) - a dictionary
>
> -locals (optional)- a
>   mapping object. Dictionary is the standard and commonly used mapping
>   type in Python. The use of globals and locals will be discussed later
>   in this article.
>
> ***Return*** Value from eval()
>
> The eval() method returns the result evaluated from the expression.
>
> *EXAMPLE:*
>
> ```
> x = 1
> print(eval('x + 1'))
> ```

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]

statement = ''

if len(list) > 4:
    statement = '[x for x in list if x%2 == 0]'
else:
    pass

print(eval(statement)) # [2, 4]
```